# How to fix nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C6.1:2][0x7fc1e7a0ead0] get output frames failed,

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication

I'm creating a login page for an app with firebase, I have succsesfully connected my app to firebase and installed the pods below.
I was expecting to get the log in option but the actual page doesnt display anything.
On the debug console I get the following error:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'authentication' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for authentication

  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'FirebaseUI'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Auth'
  pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'




end
```

the problem is that when I tap on the sign In button it opens what is suppose to be the Authentication page but I don't get any Log in option but just a white page

I've tried to remove and reinstall the pods and also to open the firebase console to disable and enable again the authentication methods (mail and password and google log in)

this is part of my view controller:

```
@IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    //Get default Auth UI object
    let AuthUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
    guard AuthUI != nil else {
        //Log error
        return
    }
    AuthUI?.delegate = self

    let authViewController = AuthUI!.authViewController()

    present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

   }

}

extension ViewController: FUIAuthDelegate {
    func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith authDataResult: AuthDataResult?, error: Error?) {

        //Check if there was an error
        if error != nil {
            //Log error
            return
        }

        //authDataResult?.user.uid
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goHome" , sender: self)

    }
}
```

```
authentication[4710:28747] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C6.1:2][0x7fc1e7a0ead0] get output frames failed, state 8196
```

(authentication is the name of the project)

Comment: That error is unlikely to be the problem https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2188#issuecomment-467115665

Comment: It appears you've overlooked a good chunk of the required login code - perhaps you intentionally omitted it but if you want help, we need to see a more complete example of your code where we can duplicate the issue. Try going back over the [Sign In](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui#sign_in) section of the Firebase Getting Started Guide and implementing the authUI.providers code. Also, double check your `func authUI` as it doesn't seem to match the delegate function that's called upon return `func authUI(_ authUI: FUIAuth, didSignInWith user: FIRUser?, error: Error?) {`

Comment: Also, sticking to standards is best practice so vars should be lowercased so they are easily identified as a var instead of a class. *authUI* instead of *AuthUI*. It's also unclear why you're using an extension as it's really not needed in this case. Lastly, unwrapping optional variables that may be nil is dangerous. It's best practice to check for & handle nil in those cases and by doing that, you can often spot coding errors.